# java pattern filter

Tags: java

i need created java pattern to filter data, like 13.6Gb, 12MB,15.5Kb
I use those code

```
  Pattern   p   =   Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\w+)"); 
  Matcher   m   =   p.matcher(content);
  String   num_letter   =   m.group(1); 
  String    union  =   m.group(2);
```

but it can't detect decimal number, so how to modify this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a conditional match for the decimal part:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?)(\\w+)");
```

Note the use of *non-capturing group* for the decimal part.

Comment: +1 and I'd suggest adding `\\s*` between the number and the units for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Have is a variation on the conditional decimal match:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d+?)+(\\w+)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, I prefer to use a tool like: http://myregexp.com/eclipsePlugin.html - it makes this waaaaay easy.

Eyeballing yours, I would say something like `(\\d+(\\.?(\\d+))?)` then you could see how many match groups you have before pulling the ones out you want. Alternatively, using named capture groups would be more readable.

-Ryan